# Merging merge commits

Tags: git, merge

Let's say I have a repository that looks the following way:

```
       /--X---Y----Z---\
A----B----C---D---E-------F-----G---
```

My question is if I can "merge" the merge commits so that the repository would like like this:

```
A----B----C---D---E-------F+(X,Y,Z)-----G----H-----I----
```

or maybe

```
A----B----C---D---E-------Q-----G----H-----I----
```

if that would make it easier.

EDIT: I'd like to make the history of a repository linear, but I'd like to make it (somehow) programatically as the repo is huge (we're talking about hunders of commits) and I just can't `rebase -i` it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `git rebase --onto` and using explicit, target and source arguments:

```
git branch branch-to-insert Z
git branch branch-following-insert I      # or preferably use the actual branch
                                          # name instead of "I"
git rebase --onto E B branch-to-insert    # rebase commits from (not including)
                                          # B, e.g. X, Y and Z
git rebase --onto branch-to-insert F branch-following-insert      # rebase G..I
```

This should give you a branch with

```
A----B----C----D----E----X----Y----Z----G----H----I----
```

For the full picture of your tree after the commands:

```
       /--X---Y----Z---\
A----B----C---D---E-------F-----G----H----I----
                   \---X---Y---Z---G---H---I---
                               ^           ^
                               |           branch-following-insert
                               branch-to-insert
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `rebase` command. This allows you to avoid using a merge and create a linear history. Basically, this command lets you take all the changes that were committed on one branch and replay them on another one. Read more about it [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

But the normal rebase workflow would only work for you if you have not done the merge yet. From your question, it seems like you have and you're looking for a way to rewrite your history. Then I would suggest looking into interactive rebasing, which does exactly that. You can change multiple commit messages, reorder commits, squash commits and split commits. Read more about it [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

**Update after the edit**: Maybe look into the `filter-branch` option. I've personally never used it but it seems to be exactly what you're looking for. From [Git's documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option:-filter-branch):

"There is another history-rewriting option that you can use if you need to rewrite a larger number of commits in some scriptable way"